# None values in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyqtgraph

I am trying to make a graph from a data which includes null value (data from pandas) using pyqtgraph.

[pyqtgraph - yellow circle has null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4poH.png)

[graph using excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOIfh.png)

i want the graph using pyqtgraph to be the same as the excel graph. in other words there will be no line in the region with null values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `yourcurve.setData(x, y, connect="finite")`

`Set data` in [plotcurveitem/plotdataitem has the keyword connect](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotcurveitem.html) which does exactly what you are looking for.

To cite from the documentation about the **connect** keyword:

> Default is **all**, indicating full connection. **pairs** causes only
>   even-numbered segments to be drawn. **finite** causes segments to be
>   omitted if they are attached to nan or inf values. For any other
>   connectivity, specify an array of boolean values.

---

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtCore

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, 10, 11])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 3, 2, 1, np.nan, 1, 2, 3])
c = b+3

w = pg.PlotWindow()
finitecurve = pg.PlotDataItem(a, b, connect="finite", pen=(255, 255, 0))
normalcurve = pg.PlotDataItem(a, c, pen=(255, 0, 0))
w.addItem(normalcurve)
w.addItem(finitecurve)
w.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

[image: Finite plot]

Comment: It seems that connect does not work in the new version